# How do I prevent my SSH tunnel port forwarding rules from disconnecting when idle?

Tags: port-forwarding, putty, connection, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I've set up some reverse port forwarding rules on my KiTTY (fork of PuTTY) client (Windows 7) through a SSH Tunnel to my remote OpenSSH server (Windows 2012). Everything works great at first, as using `netstat -ab` shows the ports are forwarded on the remote server.

The problem is the port forwarding rules are no longer in effect after a couple of hours or so of being idle, as I can use `netstat -ab` on the SSH server again to see that the ports are no longer being forwarded. The connection is reported to be working fine though. KiTTY shows it's still logged in and such.

On KiTTY, I've used 120 seconds between keep alives. Not sure what else to do to keep the rules up.

Any help would be appreciated.